# Vue-Snotify notification is not showing up

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I must implement the library Vue-Snotify to show notifications in a Vue.js project.

**Notice:** *I have no pre-experience with Vue.js! I just got this task and it needs to be done.*

I have played around with the project and tried different approaches, which got me to understand Vue.js a bit better but after trying so much, I'm left with no idea how to fix this :(

**home.js**

```
import Snotify from 'vue-snotify'
Vue.use(Snotify)

var vmHome = new Vue({
    ...
    components: {
        myFancyComponent,
        ...
    }
})
```

**myFancyComponent.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button type="button" @click="showNotif">Show</button>
    <vue-snotify></vue-snotify>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  module.exports = {
    name: "my-fancy-component",
    methods: {
        showNotif: function() {
        console.log(this.$snotify.success('Example body content'))
      }
    },
    ...
  }
</script>
```

I can trigger the notification method and it even returns me a valid object - no errors! But no trace of a notification.

```
SnotifyToast {id: 338737384058, title: null, body: "Example body content", config: {…}, eventEmitter: Vue$3, …}
```

Though I noticed an error in the console on the page's first load:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'emitter' of undefined"

found in

---> <VueSnotify>
       <MyFancyComponent>
         <Root>

TypeError: Cannot read property 'emitter' of undefined
    at VueComponent.created
```

I wonder why the VueSnotify tag wraps the MyFancyComponent and not the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you got the `methods` data type wrong, it needs to be an object and not array.

```
module.exports = {
  name: "my-fancy-component",

//---------v--- This part
  methods: {
    showNotif: function() {
      console.log(this.$snotify.success('Example body content'))
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I just mistyped myself here. In the real code it is an object :( Thanks anyway. Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm using this same component myself, and never got such error TBH. What are you currently doing with this component on the `created` hook BTW?

Comment: Nobody got. That's why I'm thinking I'm doing a very basic Vue.js mistake. I'm doing nothin on the created hook! This happens inside the original code. `this.$snotify.emitter.$on('snotify', function (toasts) {
            _this.setOptions(toasts);
        });` (vue-snotify.common.js, btw it's version 3.2.1)